# Waze deep link not working with search term

Tags: deep-linking, waze

I followed the steps at:
https://developers.google.com/waze/deeplinks/

And What ever I do I can't get waze to navigate to an address in Israel.

I want it to work without longitude and latitude

Every time I try I get a "no results found" in waze on ios.

I've tried with the following code using waze office address in israel, and keep failing.

```
<a href="https://waze.com/ul?q=יגאל%20אלון%20תל%20אביב"> <h1>hello</h1></a>
```

and also:

```
<a href="https://waze.com/ul?q=%D7%99%D7%92%D7%90%D7%9C%20%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%9F%20%D7%AA%D7%9C%20%D7%90%D7%91%D7%99%D7%91"> <h1>hello</h1></a>
```

see:
https://jsfiddle.net/3rzt6ypo/

Comment: I believe you're missing a `>`: The format for `a` tag is: `<a href="...">...</a>`

Comment: @SimonMarquis, fixed it - still doesn't work :)
Added a js filddle so it'll be easier to look at

Comment: Hi, any success with this? I need it to work without lat/long but no success, please let me know if there was a way to use it only with address.

Comment: Sorry - didn't find a way to get this to work. I ended up taking that lat long from google and sending it to waze

Comment: It is still (or again) an issue in november 2021. :( I am pretty sure that it worked for several months but now it is broken again.